# In matplotlib,how function plot's parameter 'logy' works?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

When I draw a  picture using plot in pandas timeseries. I find a parameter named `logy`. I can't make sure how it works. The documents just say
[Use log scaling on y axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

But I try figure it out and test log,log2...on y value.These values are different from the value which in the drawing window. So how `plot(logy=True)` works?

Comment: What does *different* mean? Please show an example of what you get and explain what you expect.

Comment: Yes, the data will be different if you use a log scale. If that is a problem, don't use that parameter.